# Time delay between consecutive ray castings

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

As a follow up for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58048933/3405291), I have created a [Qt3D project](https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/attachment/87502/simple-cpp.tar.xz) which is a modified version of a [Qt3D example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-simple-cpp-example.html). I'm running my project with Qt 5.13.1 on openSUSE Linux with `GCC-7`. On my project, I can use a time-delay between consecutive ray casts. I made some unexpected observations:

---

On `main.cpp` file, when I run this line, the ray casting gets stuck at some point and cannot continue:

```cpp
ConsecutiveRayCaster *consecutiveRayCaster = new ConsecutiveRayCaster(scene, TimeDelayStatus::NoDelay);
```

However, when I run this line, even when time-delay is set to `0 msec`, all the consecutive ray castings are done without any issue, :

```cpp
ConsecutiveRayCaster *consecutiveRayCaster = new ConsecutiveRayCaster(scene, TimeDelayStatus::SomeDelay, 0 /* milliseconds */);
```

---

This switch makes the difference:

```cpp
switch (m_timeDelayStatus) {
case NoDelay:
    rayCaster->trigger(origin, direction, length);
    break;
case SomeDelay:
    QTimer::singleShot(m_timeDelayBetweenRayCasts, [rayCaster, origin, direction, length](){ rayCaster->trigger(origin, direction, length); });
    break;
    }
```

I wonder why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of different behavior is in how the `trigger()` function is called. In the fist case (no delay), the execution waits until the `trigger()` function exits. However in the second case the function call is scheduled for the execution and `QTimer::singleShot()` function exits almost immediately without waiting for the `trigger()` function call returns.

Comment: Up-voted =) but I don't understand why `NoDelay` leads to the ray-castings come to an immature stop.

Comment: Because it waits until the `trigger()` is finished and returned. The key difference is the order of execution.