# Pick event is wrong sometimes but ray-cast hit is always correct

Tags: qt3d

I add a picker to entities like this:

```cpp
    
picker = new Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker(entity);
picker->setHoverEnabled(false);
picker->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("__internal object picker ") + entity->objectName());
entity->addComponent(picker);
connect(picker, &Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker::pressed, this, &EditorScene::handlePickerPress);
```

Also, at the same time, I have a ray-caster in my 3D scene:

```cpp
Qt3DRender::QRayCaster *m_rayCaster;
m_rayCaster = new Qt3DRender::QRayCaster(rootEntity);
m_rayCaster->setRunMode(Qt3DRender::QAbstractRayCaster::SingleShot);
m_rayCaster->addLayer(m_scene->layerImport());
m_rayCaster->setFilterMode(Qt3DRender::QAbstractRayCaster::FilterMode::AcceptAnyMatchingLayers);
rootEntity->addComponent(m_rayCaster);
QObject::connect(m_rayCaster, &Qt3DRender::QRayCaster::hitsChanged, this, &Preview3r::handleRayCasterHits);
```

#### Problem

The picker works fine, except when alternating mouse click from one 3D item to another. When switching the click between 3D items, the picked 3D item reported by `Qt3DRender::QPickEvent *` is the previously-clicked 3D item rather than the newly-clicked one:

```cpp
void EditorScene::handlePickerPress(Qt3DRender::QPickEvent *event)
{
    // Buggy:
    // Pressed entity is wrong when switching/alternating clicks between 3D items:
    Qt3DCore::QEntity *pressedEntity = qobject_cast<Qt3DCore::QEntity *>(sender()->parent());
}
```

#### Workaround

The solution was to use the ray-cast `Qt3DRender::QRayCasterHit` result rather than `Qt3DRender::QPickEvent *`:

```cpp
void EditorScene::handleRayCasterHit(Qt3DRender::QRayCasterHit hit)
{
    // Always works fine:
    QString name = hit.entity()->objectName();
    EditorSceneItem *item = sceneModel()->getItemByName(name);
}
```

#### Question

Why the above is observed? I know, this is *not* a reproducible code, but the code base is huge and hard to convert to a simple example.

#### Theory

A guess might be that `Qt3DRender::QPickEvent` uses ray-cast under the hood. So, ray cast under the hood of `Qt3DRender::QPickEvent` might somehow be conflicting with the other ray-cast I'm doing. Seems related to this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54901850/3405291

---

### UPDATE

#### Another problem with `QObjectPicker`

I ran into further problems with `Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker::pressed` signal. Handling that signal to process 3D items was causing segmentation faults. The segmentation fault got resolved by using the `eventFilter` method to handle mouse press events and doing ray casting.

Comment: Well, have you tried to disable all other raycasting you are doing? Maybe you could create a simple example with two spheres and check if the problem persists there. I sometimes found that more complex Qt3D code is prone to bugs.

Comment: @FlorianBlume That's right =) Before the code becomes complex, I don't remember such an observation. I'm going to try to create a simple example with two spheres...